# Referencing an object in an array using the function attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, concatenation

I have problem.
I would like to create search array function, but in array I have objects and I don't know how referencing to keys this objects from function attribute.

```
var array= [{
    name: 'Joe',
    surname: 'Smith'
}, {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Smith'
}];


function searchAndGetIndex(arrayName, key, value) {
    var cloneArray = [...arrayName];
    var saveIndex = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
        var getIndex = cloneArray.findIndex(x => x.key == value); // x.key is my problem
        if(getFilterResult !== -1) saveIndex.push(getIndex + i);
        cloneArray.splice(getIndex , 1);
    }

    return saveIndex;
}

console.log(searchAndGetIndex(array, name, 'John')); // 1
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just do the below changes in your code and it will work:**

1. When calling `searchAndGetIndex` function, change `name` to `'name'` because object keys are strings.
2. Change `x.key` to  `x[key]`
3. Change `getFilterResult` to `getIndex` in if condition

Here is running code snippet:

```js
var array= [{
    name: 'Joe',
    surname: 'Smith'
}, {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Smith'
}];


function searchAndGetIndex(arrayName, key, value) {
    var cloneArray = [...arrayName];
    var saveIndex = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++) {
        var getIndex = cloneArray.findIndex(x => x[key] == value); // x.key is my problem
        if(getIndex !== -1) saveIndex.push(getIndex + i);
        cloneArray.splice(getIndex , 1);
    }

    return saveIndex;
}

console.log(searchAndGetIndex(array, 'name', 'John')); // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this is what you want:

```js
var array= [{
    name: 'Joe',
    surname: 'Smith'
}, {
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Smith'
}];

function searchAndGetIndex(arrayName, key, value) {
    let cloneArray = [...arrayName];
    let saveIndex = [];
    
    cloneArray.forEach((e, i) => {
      if(e[key] === value) {
        saveIndex.push(i)
      }
    })
    return saveIndex;
}

console.log(searchAndGetIndex(array, 'name', 'John'));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `searchAndGetIndex`, `name` should be `'name'`, because `name` is a variable that does not exist. You are passing the *string* `'name'`, because object keys are strings.

```
var myObject = { test: 2 };
myObject[test];   // variable test is undefined
myObject.test;    // 2
myObject['test']; // 2
```

When you call `findIndex`, your `x.key` should be `x[key]`, because `x.key` means to check the property named `key` on `x`, whereas `x[key]` means to check the property with the name that is the *value of the variable `key`* (in this case, the property named `'name'`).

```
var myObject = { key: 1, test: 2 };
var key = 'test';
myObject.key;     // 1
myObject['key'];  // 1
myObject[key];    // 2
myObject['test']; // 2
```